Fonts not working with @font-face in react+vite app
I'm building a React + Vite App with usisng sass right now. For some reason I have trouble with fonts, using @font-face. Here is my _fonts.scss:
@font-face {
      font-display: swap;
      font-family: 'Monoton';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url('../assets/fonts/monoton-v19-latin-regular.woff2'),
           url('../assets/fonts/monoton-v19-latin-regular.ttf');
    }

My _variables.scss simply looks like this:
    @import 'fonts';

    $font-family-heading: 'Monoton', sans-serif;
    $font-size-heading: 24px;

And my App.module.scss:
    @import '../../sassStyles/variables';

    .heading {
      font-family: $font-family-heading;
      font-size: 120px;
}


The font gets correctly displayed in chrome, but I get the Error Messages:
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:5173/assets/fonts/monoton-v19-latin-regular.woff2
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008821359
localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:5173/assets/fonts/monoton-v19-latin-regular.ttf
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008821359

In firefox the font doesn't get displayed at all and I get those errors:
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Monoton" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1) source: http://localhost:5173/assets/fonts/monoton-v19-latin-regular.ttf 

The paths are correct, otherwise it wouldn't show in Firefox.
I couldn't find any hint, what might cause this. I found similiar cases, but not quite like mine in the end. Does anyone have an idea?

How did you download the font in the first place and have you tried using it in a simple HTML/CSS set up, just to remove any suspicion of a react etc problem?

Interessting. So if I place the font-face directly in my index.css, it does work. So I guess for some reason font-face does not work in the sass file and has to be in the index.css? So does it mean that font-face does not get compiled correctly? I'm confused but now the font is working :). Thank you!

OTS parsing errors indicate a font file was corrupted. There are several reports for webpack causing this issues when bundling all app files with incorrect transfer settings. Maybe there is a similar issue in vite.
